# Test data management solution for Oracle, DB2 and HANA

Tags: oracle, db2, hana, data-masking

I have 3 different databases (Oracle, HANA, DB2). I would like to implement data masking on Oracle database, since the data is flowing to SAP and DB2.

How can I solve this issue?

Data in Oracle is compared with DB2 and HANA, and say for example if I mask first name in Oracle then the same will not be masked at HANA and DB2. So is there a way to unmask and send data to downstream systems?

Comment: sap is not a database, it is vendor

Comment: what i meant is SAP HANA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the task can be solved by vendor's tools like IBM Optim Data Privacy. Such tools provide the capabilities for consistent masking, e.g. same input produce the same masked output, provided equivalent algorithms and parameters.

Probably by saying SAP you mean SAP HANA. This can be a bit tricky, due to missing SQL compatibility and lack of integration, but anyway this is doable too with the very same tools - just a bit more work to implement.

Comment: The challenge we're having is that we dont have any access or control over SAP or DB2. so the masking that is going to be performed on oracle , am not sure about the impact of DB2 and SAP as all systems are in nearly real time sync

Comment: The actual architecture of your system needs to be taken into account when planning for masking. Probably you need to store both masked and unmasked values, and database structure should allow that. Hard to say more without knowing more details about the system.